# Append more drop down box value to text box area

Tags: javascript, html

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function chkind1(){
    var dropdown2 = document.getElementById('dropdown1');
    var textbox = document.getElementById('textbox1');
    textbox.value=dropdown1.value;
    }
    </script>


<script type="text/javascript">
    function chkind2(){
    var dropdown3 = document.getElementById('dropdown2');
    var textbox = document.getElementById('textbox2');
    textbox.value=dropdown2.value;
    }
    </script>

<input id="textbox1" name="size" type="text" />
<input id="textbox2" name="copies" type="text" />

<select onchange=chkind1()' id='dropdown1'>
<option value='Nil'>Select Print Size</option>
<option value = '$file - 5x7'>5x7</option>
<option value = '$file - 6x8'>6x8</option>
</select>

<select onchange='chkind2()' id='dropdown2'>
<option value = 'Nil'>Select how many Copies</option>
<option value = '1'>1</option>
<option value = '2'>2</option>
</select>

</html>
```

Hi all, trying to achieve on the first drop down box (size), is not to overwrite each selection but to append or add each selection one after the other. E.G 5x7, 6x8, etc etc.

I have had a go but can't seem to get it right, could I please have some help on this.
Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your value assignment to append your selection to the current value:

```
textbox.value += ' ' + dropdown1.value;
```

Add whatever characters in between the quotes to separate your entries.

**UPDATE:**

Per question in the comment to remove the value if it is selected again.

```
if(textbox.value.indexOf(dropdown1.value) == -1) {
    textbox.value = textbox.value.replace(dropdown1.value, '');
} else {
    textbox.value += ' ' + dropdown1.value;
}
```

Check to see if the value is contained in the string.  `indexOf` returns -1 if the value is note present.  Then you assign the value to be the string with that value removed.

Comment: Worked perfect thanks! Forgot to ask is there away so that if you select the same value it will remove it from the text box?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than over-write your previous textbox selection, add to it:

```
textbox.value += ", " + dropdown1.value;
```